# Gazebo SDF model loading in Groovy

Tags: ros, gazebo, spawn-model, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a correct Gazebo 1.2 [model](http://pastebin.com/Q0nLVDLa), slightly modified from the [Gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.2/build_robot/mobile_base). If that model with it's manifest.xml is in ~/.gazebo/models, then Gazebo of ROS can see and load this model.

Now I would like to load this model with the spawn_model script of ROS gazebo package.

I have tried this command:

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -gazebo -file /home/ronald/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_heightmap/Media/models/robot1/model.sdf -model myrobot
```

and tried with this launch file

```
<launch>
<param name="robot_model" textfile="$(find gazebo_heightmap)/Media/models/robot1/model.sdf" />
<node name="spawn_robot1" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-gazebo -param robot_model -model myrobot" respawn="false" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

In both cases, Gazebo node gives error messages

```
Error [parser.cc:675] XML Element[origin], child of element[model] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[model]
Error [parser.cc:666] Error reading element <model>
Error [parser.cc:366] Unable to read element <gazebo>
Error:   Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
     at line 61 in /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-urdfdom-0.2.6-1precise-20121225-1343/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Error [parser_urdf.cc:1659] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Warning [parser.cc:374] Gazebo SDF has no <gazebo> element in file[urdf string]
Error [parser.cc:318] parse as old urdf model file failed.
Error [World.cc:1190] Unable to read sdf string
```

To me it seems that the model description files must be different to load it with spawn_model, but how?

**Update:**
The model does not contain  element, as suggested.
The model also loads if it is included in a world description file. Just the spawn_model does not work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52076/gazebo-sdf-model-loading-in-groovy/) by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2013-01-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-15**:
Starting since Sep 2012, **all** `gazebo` related questions should be asked on [new `gazebo` specific QA community](http://answers.gazebosim.org/). Thank you for your cooperation!

See also [this thread](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/595/why-even-gazebo-ros-questions-should-be-asked-on/).

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-15**:
I keep, however, the thread open since the discussion has already been going on.

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-01-27**:
But Gazebo can load this model easily, it seems just the spawn_model node that can't load the model. Isn't this node part of ROS?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-27**:
Personally I agree with you. But the developers of Gazebo want all Qs to move to the new QA site. Please see the link I cited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that the problem is not with your launch code but with your description file in the sdf format. The first line of the error messages says that you have used an element called , however there are no origins defined in sdf, and gazebo defines  instead.

I didn't see any origin in the tutorial page you referenced however, were you to post the sdf file, that may help.

cheers

Peter

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-01-12**:
Link to the model file was included in the first post also : http://pastebin.com/Q0nLVDLa
There is no  tag used anywhere.

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-01-13**:
well what version of gazebo is installed?

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-01-13**:
It is Gazebo-1.2.5 that come with Groovy.

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-01-15**:
You're also mixing ' and " this could also lead to problems perhaps? I see the tutorial mixes them also but I think it caused problems in my simulation.